# XPath query to select any descendant without a specific value of a specific attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I have bee trying to construct an XPath query that basically selects everything but excludes certain nodes.

This is the XML I am going through:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<task>
  <title id="30014">Instructions</title>
  <taskbody>
    <context>
      <p>Your box has a document.</p>
      <p audience="print">To get the document:</p>
      <p audience="web">
        <xref href="/node/6308" scope="external">Click here</xref> to get the document.
      </p>
    </context>
    <steps audience="print">
      <step>
        <cmd>Go to 
          <u>www.google.com</u>.
        </cmd>
      </step>
      <step>
        <cmd>Click on the “Resource” button.</cmd>
        <info>
          <fig frame="all">
            <image href="resource.ai" height="1.650in" width="4.500in"/>
          </fig>
        </info>
      </step>
      <step>
        <cmd>Click on “Manuals”.</cmd>
      </step>
      <step>
        <cmd>Click on “Shipping”.</cmd>
      </step>
      <step>
        <cmd>You can save or print it from your browser window.</cmd>
      </step>
    </steps>
  </taskbody>
</task>
```

I need to select everything inside the  where audience does not equal "print".

I have been trying all sorts of ways I have been reading about but none seems to work exactly the way I neeed.

This is the latest one that get almost there but not quite:

```
task/taskbody//*[not(@audience = "print")]
```

The problem is, it does fine at stripping out nodes 1 level down that have the "print" value. However, the first `<p>` that has the "print" value is inside of `<context>`. That node never seems to not get selected.

Here is the result of the query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
<context>
      <p>Your box has a document.</p>
      <p audience="print">To get the document:</p>
      <p audience="web">
        <xref href="/node/6308" scope="external">Click here</xref> to get the document.
      </p>
    </context>

<p>Your box has a document.</p>

<p audience="web">
        <xref href="/node/6308" scope="external">Click here</xref> to get the document.
      </p>

<xref href="/node/6308" scope="external">Click here</xref>

<step>
        <cmd>Go to 
          <u>www.google.com</u>.
        </cmd>
      </step>

<cmd>Go to 
          <u>www.google.com</u>.
        </cmd>

<u>www.google.com</u>

<step>
        <cmd>Click on the “Resource” button.</cmd>
        <info>
          <fig frame="all">
            <image height="1.650in" href="resource.ai" width="4.500in"/>
          </fig>
        </info>
      </step>

<cmd>Click on the “Resource” button.</cmd>

<info>
          <fig frame="all">
            <image height="1.650in" href="resource.ai" width="4.500in"/>
          </fig>
        </info>

<fig frame="all">
            <image height="1.650in" href="resource.ai" width="4.500in"/>
          </fig>

<image height="1.650in" href="resource.ai" width="4.500in"/>

<step>
        <cmd>Click on “Manuals”.</cmd>
      </step>

<cmd>Click on “Manuals”.</cmd>

<step>
        <cmd>Click on “Shipping”.</cmd>
      </step>

<cmd>Click on “Shipping”.</cmd>

<step>
        <cmd>You can save or print it from your browser window.</cmd>
      </step>

<cmd>You can save or print it from your browser window.</cmd>

</result>
```

It grabs the nodes without the attributes, it grabs the nodes with "web" and most of the nodes with "print" except for that one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: doubt: when you're trying to exclude the element with `audience="print" ` shouldnt the entire `<steps ..> ... </steps>` node, including the `<step>` child nodes, be also excluded? is that you expectation or not ?

Answer (score 2):

This expression will select all elements which do not have any `@audience` attribute, and the ones that do but contain a value which is not the string `print`:

```
//*[not(descendant::*[@audience='print']) and not(ancestor-or-self::*[@audience='print'])]
```

The way it is written above it will select the `<title>`, the first and third `<p>` children of `<context>`. It won't select the `<steps>` or the second `<p>` because they have an `audience` attribute containing `print`.

To exclude the title (reducing the context to `taskbody`) use:

```
//task/taskbody//*[not(descendant::*[@audience='print']) and not(ancestor-or-self::*[@audience='print'])]
```

Comment: I tried this query and this is the result:

    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
<title id="30014">Instructions</title>

<p>Your box has a document.</p>

<p audience="web">
        <xref href="/node/6308" scope="external">Click here</xref> to get the document.
      </p>

<xref href="/node/6308" scope="external">Click here</xref>

</result>`.

It looks like it is stripping out too much.

Comment: Isn't that what you want? All the nodes that *do not have an `audience` attribute with the value `print`*?

Comment: Wait, sorry, I think you are right. (I have been staring at this XML way too long today.

Comment: What are your other restrictions then?

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the only problem is that the results include 1 of the nodes twice. The `<xref>` is showing up in the result in the context of the `<p>` and by itself. So ideally, the result would contain this: `<title id="30014">Instructions</title>

<p>Your box has a document.</p>

<p audience="web">
        <xref href="/node/6308" scope="external">Click here</xref> to get the document.
 </p>`. (Same as above but without the second instance of the `<xref>`.

Comment: I see. That's because of the `//` (descendant-or-self) axis, which selects each individual node. Are you restricted to XPath 1.0?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I am using the Feeds XPath Parser in Drupal to import XML content and that module is limited to 1.0